# How to copy Columns in one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to copy Columns A-F in 120 sheets into one sheet (combining them). How can I complete this? Will it need to be a macro? I want it to be dynamic (not just ctrl C - Ctrl V) so that if something in one sheet changes, the combined changes. All 120+ sheets are in one workbook.

Comment: Yes it will be dynamic. There are a few ways to do this, what have you tried? You're essentially using loops: loop through each worksheet in workbook, copy the range, and paste that range to the Main Worksheet.  Look on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) too, this has been asked frequently.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't think looping is a dynamic way because you are basically copy and paste them. The only way I can think about is to import the sheets using Power Query or some sort of connections.

Comment: @ZhongjieShen - I just meant "dynamic" in that, you'll have to adjust (I assume) the range sizes for each worksheet.

Comment: 1. How, exactly, should they be combined?  Still just cols A:F on the combined sheet, with the contents from each source concatenated below to make really long columns, or each sheet's contents in a new set of cols on the combined sheet (Sheet1 A:F = Combined A:F, Sheet2 A:F = Combined G:L, etc.)?  If the 1st case, how do you identify the sources on the combined sheet?  Can the number of rows on any sheet grow?  Are there equal numbers of rows in each col on every sheet?  Does each sheet have the same number of rows?  Can there be included blank rows?  (cont'd)

Comment: If so, do you keep them or compact the data on the combined sheet?  2. If you want it dynamic in the sense that the combined sheet must always reflect the current state of changing source data, you need cell references rather than copying anything.  If the number of rows is not fixed, you need to reference as many rows as there can possibly be and hide ones that aren't populated.  As you can see, there is too much ambiguity for people to be able to answer and reliably give you what you need. (cont'd)

Comment: Please make the description a lot more specific about the exact nature of the source data and how it should be combined.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not recommend keep a workbook with 120 sheets. This makes it extremely difficult to navigate and make changes.
If I understand this correctly, you are looking for a way to merge individual columns in 120 sheets into a new sheet.

For instance,

Sheet 1:

```
(Column A)    
1     
2     
3
```

Sheet 2:

```
(Column A)
a     
b     
c
```

...

Combined Sheet:

```
(Column A)
1     
2     
3    
a     
b     
c
```

If this is the thing you want to do, check out **Power Query**.

- Import the entire Workbook.
- Go to 'Edit'
- Expand the 'data' column.
- Load to wherever you prefer.
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

If you make any changes to the original sheets, click the 'Refresh All' in Data tab to retrieve the changes to the new combined table.